# How to update the property values of an Active Directory user

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

"I want to update the values ​​of several properties of an Active Directory user at the same time, 
I try the following method but it does not pass ..."

```
       public void SetAdInfo(string objectFilter, 
                  Dictionary<string, object> objectName, 
                  string ldapPath)
    {
        string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        mySearcher.Filter = "(cn=" + objectFilter + ")";
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("" + objectName + "");
        SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();
        if (result != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entryToUpdate = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

                foreach (var prop in objectName)
                {

                    entryToUpdate.Properties[prop.Key].Value = prop.Value;

                entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();
                }

        }
        entry.Close();
        entry.Dispose();
        mySearcher.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: You need to better explain how the code is failing rather than saying it "does not pass".

Comment: the query works without beug but there is no result

Comment: Can you show us an example on how do objectFilter, objectName and ldapPath look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely your problem right here:

```
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("" + objectName + "");
```

The `objectName` parameter is a `Dictionary<string, object>`, but you're using it like a string. When you do that, .NET calls the `.ToString()` method on the object, which will end up being something you don't want, like "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]".

That's likely what's messing up your search.

But you aren't reading the properties of the search results anyway. You're just calling `.GetDirectoryEntry()` on each result. So you don't even need to set `PropertiesToLoad`. So just take that line out.

If you did want to read each property from the search results, you need to add each property individually, so you would need to loop through the `Dictionary` and add each `Key` to the `PropertiesToLoad`:

```
foreach (var prop in objectName) {
    mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(prop.Key);
}
```